# How to do a ORDER BY inside a INNER JOIN to get last status update?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-5.5, groupwise-maximum

I need to get records of 2 tables using filters and sorting.
Tables: ra_pedidos, ra_pedido_has_pedido_status

It worked perfectly in MySQL5.0, but now in 5.5 it does not bring the correct result anymore.

I need in the same line to bring the date of the first status and last change of status of each request and ignore the canceled ones.

Example search (ra_pedido_has_pedido_status):

```
SELECT id_pedido, id_pedido_status, data
    FROM ra_pedido_has_pedido_status
    WHERE id_pedido IN (86291, 86745, 86622);
```

Result:

```
+-----------+------------------+---------------------+
| id_pedido | id_pedido_status | data                |
+-----------+------------------+---------------------+
|     86291 |                1 | 2017-10-30 11:16:12 |
|     86291 |                2 | 2017-10-30 14:14:53 |
|     86291 |                3 | 2017-10-31 08:18:47 |
|     86291 |               11 | 2017-11-07 12:08:04 |
|     86622 |                1 | 2017-11-04 12:23:21 |
|     86622 |                2 | 2017-11-04 12:47:33 |
|     86622 |                3 | 2017-11-06 08:24:20 |
|     86622 |               90 | 2017-11-07 08:40:55 |
|     86745 |                1 | 2017-11-07 10:59:51 |
|     86745 |                2 | 2017-11-07 11:09:46 |
+-----------+------------------+---------------------+
```

Now report SQL:
[EDIT] Explain: `JOIN` get first match row, then the `ORDER BY` on `SELECT` inside this join force to get last row. Note that `id_pedido` 86622 should not list because it is canceled (last `id_pedido_status` = 90), and this is filtered in `HAVING`

```
SELECT  o.id_pedido AS id, pus.id_pedido_status, pus.data
    FROM  ra_pedido AS o
    INNER JOIN  
    (
        SELECT  ra_pedido_has_pedido_status.*
            FROM  ra_pedido_has_pedido_status
            ORDER BY  data DESC
    ) AS pus  ON o.id_pedido = pus.id_pedido
    WHERE  o.id_pedido IN (86291, 86745, 86622)
    GROUP BY  o.id_pedido
    HAVING  id_pedido_status < 90
    ORDER BY  data DESC;
```

This is the result using MySQL 5.0, the expected:

```
+-------+------------------+---------------------+
| id    | id_pedido_status | data                |
+-------+------------------+---------------------+
| 86291 |               11 | 2017-11-07 12:08:04 |
| 86745 |                2 | 2017-11-07 11:09:46 |
+-------+------------------+---------------------+
```

And this is the result using MySQL 5.5, not expected:

```
+-------+------------------+---------------------+
| id    | id_pedido_status | data                |
+-------+------------------+---------------------+
| 86745 |                1 | 2017-11-07 10:59:51 |
| 86622 |                1 | 2017-11-04 12:23:21 |
| 86291 |                1 | 2017-10-30 11:16:12 |
+-------+------------------+---------------------+
```

What do I need to change in SQL?
*Thanks and sorry my english...*

Comment: I don't believe you got those first results in any RDBMS given the same data. You group by `id_pedido` and there are three of them in your data. You had best get three out. Your ORDER BY also doesn't add up. All that being said, it's entirely likely you'll get different results for `id_pedido_status` and `data` because you don't aggregate or include those fields in your GROUP BY. Any other RDBMS would reject this query with an error. If you share some sample data from these two tables and your desired results (and an explanation of the logic to get there) we can help out more.

Comment: Sadly MySQL does not reject poorly written GROUP BY :)

Comment: `GROUP BY` is right, I want to list orders just 1 time. And I need join only the most recent row from `ra_pedido_has_pedido_status` for each order. What I want is get same result in a newest MySQL version using the data above... if you have other way to do that, I'ill be glad in learn. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be a groupwise max problem; see the items on the related tag.  SQL standard (and MySQL) do not guarantee the order of things in the way you gave them; you were lucky that it worked in one version.